# Rails Validate Uniqueness of certain Id in Join Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Users and Triggers Table, and a join table called TriggersUser

Is it possible to define the scope of **just one** trigger id per user? For example, each user can only have `trigger_id: 1` once, while `trigger_id: 3` can be stored with that user in the join table as many times as needed.

Is it possible to defined the scope of the model for uniqueness of trigger id and user id, but only for specific trigger_ids?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think that's possible with database-level restriction, but you can do that in [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: You should bold "the scope" instead of "just one", LOL

Comment: I misunderstood the OP's requirements.

Comment: Maybe you want to put "shared trigger" and "unique trigger" in two `Model`s? So a user belongs to a unique trigger; a unique trigger has many users; a user has and belongs to many shared triggers, a shared trigger has and belongs to many users. Then you define a helper `User#triggers` that appends the unique trigger to the shared triggers.

Comment: That's a really good idea! I didn't think to separate them. Thanks I'll look into that @FranklinYu

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the amount of times a trigger can be used.

```
class AddAllowedUsesToTriggers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :triggers, :allowed_uses, :integer, default: 1
  end
end
```

Then add a custom validation which checks the count of `user_triggers` against the maximum allowed.

```
class User
  has_many :triggers, through: :user_triggers
  has_many :user_triggers
end

class Trigger
  has_many :users, through: :user_triggers
  has_many :user_triggers

  def available_to?(user)
    # lets use -1 to represent infinity
    return true if allowed_uses == -1
    # otherwise evaluate if the user has reached the max allowed number
    (allowed_uses - user_triggers.where(user: user).count) > 0
  end
end

class UserTrigger
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trigger

  validates :trigger_available

  def trigger_available
    unless trigger.available_to?(user)
      errors[:trigger] = 'has been expended by user'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the idea of available_to. Let me play with that for a sec. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not aware of any straight forward way to create a database level constraint which enforces this rule though so race conditions could be an issue. For example if you double click and the both requests check the count on `user_triggers` before either has finished inserting than two rows could be inserted in `user_triggers` even if only one was allowed. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Answer (score 0):

Why not add validation on `TriggerUser` model?

```
validates :trigger_id, unique: {scope: :user_id}
```

Of course one needs to also add a unique index on those two fields because rails unique validation [will not ensure uniqueness](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) in some cases